# Как получить данные json через retrofit 2 и Gson?

Tags: java, json, retrofit, gson, pojo

Собственно сам код:

класс активити
MainActivity.java

```
package com.ocean_shop.myapplication;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.ocean_shop.myapplication.POJO.Message;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Credentials;
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";
    String username = "USER";
    String password = "PASS";


    public interface MessagesApi {


        @GET("http://MYSERVER/ocean_shop/odata/standard.odata/AccumulationRegister_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8/Turnovers(StartPeriod=datetime'2018-02-06',%20EndPeriod=datetime'2018-02-07')?$format=json;odata=nometadata")
            //Call<S<Message>> getMetadata();
        Call<Message.Value> getTurnover();

        //Call<List<Message>> messages();

    }
    //http://77.34.10.185/ocean_shop/odata/standard.odata/

    private String BASE_URL = "http://MYSERVER/ocean_shop/odata/standard.odata/";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request originalRequest = chain.request();
                Request.Builder builder = originalRequest.newBuilder().
                        method("GET", originalRequest.body()).
                        header("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8").
                        header("Authorization", Credentials.basic(username, password));
                Request newRequest = builder.build();
                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        }).build();


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://77.34.10.185/ocean_shop/odata/standard.odata/").
                client(okHttpClient).
                addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).
                build();
        MessagesApi messagesApi = retrofit.create(MessagesApi.class);


        Call<Message.Value> messages = messagesApi.getTurnover();

        messages.enqueue(new Callback<Message.Value>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Message.Value> call, Response<Message.Value> response) {
                //log("response.headers() " + response.body());
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    log("result " + String.valueOf(response.body()));
                } else {
                    log("Code " + response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Message.Value> call, Throwable t) {

            }

        });

    }

    private void log(String s) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, s);
    }


}
```

класс pojo
Message.java

```
package com.ocean_shop.myapplication.POJO;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Message {
    /*
    @SerializedName("odata.metadata")
    @Expose
    private String metadata;
    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private Map<String, ArrayList<Integer> > value;

    public Message(String metadata, Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> value){
        this.metadata=metadata;
        this.value=value;
    }

    public String getMetadata() {
        return metadata;
    }

    public void setMetadata(String metadata) {
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }

    public Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }*/
    @SerializedName("odata.metadata")
    @Expose
    private String odataMetadata;
    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private List<Value> value = null;


    public String getOdataMetadata(){
        return  odataMetadata;
    }

    public void setOdataMetadata(String odataMetadata) {
        this.odataMetadata = odataMetadata;
    }

    public List<Value> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(List<Value> value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public class Value {

        @SerializedName("Номенклатура_Key")
        @Expose
        public String номенклатураKey;
        @SerializedName("ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры_Key")
        @Expose
        public String характеристикаНоменклатурыKey;
        @SerializedName("ЗаказПокупателя")
        @Expose
        public String заказПокупателя;
        @SerializedName("ЗаказПокупателя_Type")
        @Expose
        public String заказПокупателяType;
        @SerializedName("ДоговорКонтрагента_Key")
        @Expose
        public String договорКонтрагентаKey;
        @SerializedName("ДокументПродажи")
        @Expose
        public String документПродажи;
        @SerializedName("ДокументПродажи_Type")
        @Expose
        public String документПродажиType;
        @SerializedName("Подразделение_Key")
        @Expose
        public String подразделениеKey;
        @SerializedName("Проект_Key")
        @Expose
        public String проектKey;
        @SerializedName("Организация_Key")
        @Expose
        public String организацияKey;
        @SerializedName("Контрагент_Key")
        @Expose
        public String контрагентKey;
        @SerializedName("КоличествоTurnover")
        @Expose
        public int количествоTurnover;
        /*@SerializedName("СтоимостьTurnover")
        @Expose
        public int стоимостьTurnover;*/
        @SerializedName("СтоимостьTurnover")
        @Expose
        public int Turnover;
        @SerializedName("СтоимостьБезСкидокTurnover")
        @Expose
        public int стоимостьБезСкидокTurnover;
        @SerializedName("НДСTurnover")
        @Expose
        public int НДСTurnover;


        public Integer getTurnover() {
            return Turnover;
        }

        public void setTurnover(Integer Turnover) {
            this.Turnover = Turnover;
        }
    }

}
```

Примерно то что находиться на сервере
JSON

```
{
"odata.metadata": "http://MYSERVER/ocean_shop/odata/standard.odata/$metadata#Collection(StandardODATA.AccumulationRegister_ПродажиСебестоимость_Turnover)",
"value": [
{
"Номенклатура_Key": "cd1beaa2-eb72-11e7-b49e-3085a93c0618",
"ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"ЗаказПокупателя": "",
"ЗаказПокупателя_Type": "StandardODATA.Undefined",
"ДокументОприходования": "c04e6bb4-eb77-11e7-8d51-3085a93c0618",
"ДокументОприходования_Type": "StandardODATA.Document_ОприходованиеТоваров",
"Подразделение_Key": "99c2e4c6-a655-11e7-a216-3085a93c0618",
"Проект_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"КоличествоTurnover": 1,
"СтоимостьTurnover": 2200
},
{
"Номенклатура_Key": "725d9200-9ddf-11e7-a202-3085a93c0618",
"ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"ЗаказПокупателя": "",
"ЗаказПокупателя_Type": "StandardODATA.Undefined",
"ДокументОприходования": "2d459277-a359-11e7-a211-3085a93c0618",
"ДокументОприходования_Type": "StandardODATA.Document_ОприходованиеТоваров",
"Подразделение_Key": "99c2e4c6-a655-11e7-a216-3085a93c0618",
"Проект_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"КоличествоTurnover": 1,
"СтоимостьTurnover": 50
},
{
"Номенклатура_Key": "3bb4dcbe-9ddc-11e7-a202-3085a93c0618",
"ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"ЗаказПокупателя": "",
"ЗаказПокупателя_Type": "StandardODATA.Undefined",
"ДокументОприходования": "31bc57f3-a76b-11e7-a217-3085a93c0618",
"ДокументОприходования_Type": "StandardODATA.Document_ОприходованиеТоваров",
"Подразделение_Key": "99c2e4c6-a655-11e7-a216-3085a93c0618",
"Проект_Key": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"КоличествоTurnover": 2,
"СтоимостьTurnover": 162
}
]
}
```

MYSERVER, USER, PASS содержат мои значения

Собственно мне нужно получить значение поля в JSON СтоимостьTurnover примеров в интернете которые я смог разобрать не помогли. Помогите может перестроить запрос или укажите направление для решение задачи.

Comment: Поля серьезно так называется?

Comment: Да. Это данные 1С.